# Changing a target value that minimize the product being outside the specifications in quality control

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, quality-control

I was doing problems in the [article here.](http://elearning.vtu.ac.in/10/enotes/06IPIM65/Mod10-NVN.pdf)

In the question on **page 16**  [image]

I don't understand part b) how to find a target value that minimize the product being outside the specifications.  Can someone please explain to me how it was decided to change process mean from 125 to 127?

Also in part a) I did it as percentage of non confirming=$P(X<119)+P(X>135)$

As $X$~$N(125,2.66487)$ I found $P(X<119)+P(X>135)=0.596$%. But that is different from the answer given.Is my method wrong?

Comment: (b) The normal distribution is symmetric & unimodal. So imagine nudging it along relative to the specs - at what point does a nudge push more of the density over the upper spec than it pulls over the lower spec? (b) Give more of your working.